# Setting Up Local DNS Server If Router Has No Configurable DNS

Tags: networking, router, dns

This is my first post here really trying to get my head around this so bear with me.

I had a tp link router provided by work that allowed me to setup DNS like this.

```
/.local.test.example.com/192.168.111.202
```

With the ip being the ip of my computer.

This worked great working on devices that allowed debug setup for example Samsung TV debug you can set the host pc ip to my computers ip 192.168.111.202 and DNS would be handled via the router allowing me to load a local url on Samsung TV for development ex: local.test.example.com

[image]

We have now been given a router that doesnt allow the DNS to be set.

What other solutions do I have I have tried Dnsmasq which does work on Samsung TV as it has the debug option but not on other devices that dont.

How do I setup to send anything coming from local.test.example.com over my local network to my computer ip 192.168.111.202?

The devices are connected to my router via Ethernet so I guess when I try and open local.test.example.com in one of the devices internet browsers (that doesnt have a debug option) it then goes to the router the router has no dns config so it then send the request to the DNS primary server google etc 8.8.8.8 this obviously has no record for local.test.example.com so it fails.

Apologies if this doesnt make sense hopefully someone understands what I am trying to achieve and can point my in the right direction I have looked a Pi Hole and even using a Raspberry Pi as a router but dont want to invest a lot of time in this if it wont really resolve my issue. Ideally the router would have configurable DNS like the old one but no such luck.

Thanks

Comment: so are you saying that your retired a router that performed dns masquerading with one that does not? first do you need name resolution on your LAN? if not is there any reason you couldn't point all the lans hosts to use a publically accessible dns infrastructure like layer3's, google's, or cloudflare's (just to name a few common choices)?

Comment: What make/model is your new router?  What is handing out 8.8.8.8 via DHCP?  My guess is its configured on the router, in which case you can change it to pount to your DNSMasq server instead.

Comment: I'm assuming `local.test.example.com` is referring to a LAN served webpage? If so, the only two ways I'm aware of to make that work is to either add a route/DNS in the router for `local.test.example.com` to LAN IP `192.168.111.202:<port#>` or to add the route/DNS on the client device - without one or the other, there's no way I'm aware of to route a request for `local.test.example.com` to `192.168.111.202:<port#>`, as the router, nor client device, has no way to know how to route traffic to `local.test.example.com:<port#>`.